How can I launch an Xorg server on another tty?
I found this command, which lets me launch an Xorg on tty8
sudo systemd-run     --property PAMName=login     --property User="$user"     --property StandardInput=tty     --property TTYPath=/dev/tty8     sh -c 'chvt 9 && exec startx > /tmp/xorg_output.log 2>&1'

I issue this command over ssh, while LightDM is displayed on the screen, meaning I have not logged in.
Trying to interact with the Xorg on tty8 is not possible, as my keyboard and mouse are totally frozen.
If I chvt 7, then the mouse and keyboard are working again;)
I’m a bit confused about how I can troubleshoot this;) Any pointers? I'm on NixOS.
I also posted this question on UNIX, but it has gotten no reply.

If you don't care about the why, I'd say you may want to just go with the "auto login with a getty instance + (conditionally) auto startx with a shell rc file" approach (in which case the X server will be started in a session).
